# Passing NSString returning null in next ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an **NSString from one view controller to the next**. However I cannot seem to get it to function properly and I have set up a simple  `NSLog(@"%@", myString);` before I try to 
`[vc2 setString:myString];` which prints the correct string, and also in the second viewController and it is coming back as null so clearly I am doing something wrong. Here is my code.

first viewController

```
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "City.h"
#import "VideoController.h"
#import "Helper.h"

@interface DetailController ()

@end

@implementation DetailController
@synthesize city, ClubName, Price, Vip, Promo, remain,p,deal,money,camera,cam,tweet,post;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *highlightedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"]; 

    [Helper customizeBarButton:self.tweet image:highlightedButtonImage highlightedImage:highlightedButtonImage];

    UIImage *faceButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"]; 

    [Helper customizeBarButton:self.post image:faceButtonImage highlightedImage:faceButtonImage];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIFont *labelFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:20.0];
    UIFont *myFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:30.0];
    UIFont *titleFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:40.0];
    NSString * name= self.city.clubName;
    NSString * line= self.city.clubLine;
    NSString * description= self.city.promo;
    NSString * price= self.city.price;


    remain.font=labelFont;
    remain.text=@"VIP Remaining :";
    p.font=labelFont;
    p.text=@"Price :";
    money.font=myFont;

    deal.font=labelFont;
    deal.text=@"Promotions :";

    ClubName.font=titleFont;
    ClubName.text=name;
    Vip.font=myFont;
    Vip.text=line;
    Price.font=myFont;
    Price.text=price;
    Promo.font=labelFont;
    Promo.text=description;
 }

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender 
{
     VideoController *vc2 = [[VideoController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [vc2 setCam:self.city.camera];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Second ViewController

```
#import "VideoController.h"
#import "City.h"

@interface VideoController ()

@end

@implementation VideoController
@synthesize webView,city,cam;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    NSLog(@"%@", cam);
    image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"32.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"31.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"30.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"29.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"28.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"27.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"26.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"25.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"24.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"23.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"22.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"21.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"20.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"19.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"15.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"14.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.tiff"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.tiff"],nil];

    [image setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    image.animationDuration = 10.0;
    [image startAnimating];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)yourMethod
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you using a storyboard to go from the first view controller to the second?

Comment: You have shown where you set it but not where you push the `viewController`

Comment: @Simon McLoughlin i have added an IBAction button now to push the viewController but still cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong

Comment: Please answer my question. Are you using a storyboard with a segue?

Comment: @Fogmeister yes I am using a storyboard with a toolbar button to push VideoController

Comment: OK, then you should just add my code to your first view controller. You don't need to run it yourself. Don't add an IBAction. Just keep the segue and add my code. I didn't say you had to connect it as an IBAction.

Comment: If you are using a storyboard then you can't load it the way that you have done in your edit.

Comment: Your drip feeding information and its confusing everyone. Your using a storyboard ok. Are you using a segue?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I think he was using storyboard and segue but then from my answer he removed the segue and attached his button action to `prepareForSegue`. Just needs to put the segue back and add the code I put in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing from the absence of a push to the second VC that you're using a segue in a storyboard to go from the first to the second.

If this is correct then you should do something glide this in the first view controller...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    VideoController *vc2 = segue.destinationViewController;

    [vc2 setCam:self.city.camera];
}
```

And remove the lines that deal with VC2 in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have edited my code and created an IBAction and button instead to push the next ViewController but still no luck..

Comment: @user3492592 An IBAction to what? Are you using a storyboard and segue? If so you don't need an inaction to anything. The segue will trigger this code.

Comment: I tried using your prepareForSegue method and it still returned null

Comment: @user3492592 Yes, because you attached an IBAction to it. You still need to use the segue. Just add this code to the first view controller. You don't run this yourself.

Comment: Great thanks I finally figured it out. Sorry Im very new to Objective C so thanks for your help and being patient!

Comment: I just realized something I didn't thought and knew it. +1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where does the created VideoController is used? In your post it's getting created but never used - you must use the same created (and assigned) instance in order to see the right value...

Comment: I have edited my code and now am using an IBAction method to push the next ViewController onto the stack but still no luck..Im not sure I understand how i am not using it..I am extremely new to objective c so i apologize for my lack of knowledge